# match any character until the space

Tags: javascript, regex

Given String:

```
Failed entity=/data/192a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa/cdata/data_0;version=2181 some lorem ipsum text.
```

Desired output

```
/data/192a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa/cdata/data_0;version=2181
```

Attempt

```
error.message.match(/\/data(^\s*)/)
```

I want to extract from `/data/...` until the space after `version=xxxx`

please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the negation (`^`) within a character group (`[..]`):

```
/\/data([^\s]*)/
```

Nevertheless this is a rather unsafe way to extract a url: it is possible that the word `/data` is written before and after the real url. You should consider a more failsafe test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^\/data+[-\/;\w=]+/g
```